# Async request problem with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções, request, async

O problema é com variáveis por que a função `async` esta executando depois da atribuição da variável. o que posso fazer para a função executar e esperar ela terminar para pegar o valor da variável?

```js
var request = require('request');
function information(callback) {
    var options = {
        url: "http://someurl.com",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Token: "MV"
        }
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            try {
                json = JSON.parse(body);
                callback(json);
            } catch (error) {
                error = 'error'
                callback(error);
            }

        }
    })
}
var foo;
information(function (bar) {
        if (bar) {
            console.log(foo);
            foo = bar;
            console.log(foo);
        }
    }) 
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De forma direta, do jeito que está, você não pode usar foo fora do callback passado por information(). Existem dois jeitos de tornar o código assíncrono principal mais legível. Um é transformar seu método original em uma Promise e usar a cadeia .then():

```
function information_p()
{
    return new Promise(function (ok, nok) {
        information(function (resp) {
            ok(resp);
        });
    });
}

information_p().then(console.log);
```

Uma Promise pode ser usada com a palavra-chave await em vez de .then(), porém await só pode ser usado dentro de uma função async, o que cria um problema "ovo ou galinha" para fazer o primeiro await. Uma maneira é criar uma função async anônima e invocá-la:

```
(async function () {
    var foo = await information_p();
    console.log(foo);
})();
```

De um jeito ou de outro, você nunca escapa do fato de estar adiando o momento de mostrar o resultado de information() pelo console.log().